# How to use useContext data with properties

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, use-context

I'm using useContext in a component page, and it correctly gets datas through useContext in a type of a property.

**colorContex.js**

```
import { createContext, useEffect, useState, useContext } from 'react';

// create context object
export const ColorContext = createContext({});

export const ProductsProvider = (props) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchAPI() {
      const res = await fetch(url);
      const posts = await res.json();
      setData(posts);
    }
    fetchAPI();
  }, []);
  return <ColorContext.Provider value={data}>{props.children}</ColorContext.Provider>;
};
```

**headerDefault.tsx**

```
  const colors = useContext(ColorContext);
  console.log(colors);
  // the data shows up correctly in console log
  const colorData = colors.response;
  // the error message( the property doesn't exist type {}. )
```

[Google development](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cB3XA.png)

the data is correct and a type of property.
How can I get property datas?

[image: ColorData]

Comment: can show how colors data look or its schema

Comment: yes, I added it!!!!

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is this line:

```
export const ColorContext = createContext({});
```

TypeScript infers the context type from this line and `{}` does not have a `.response` property.

To fix this, define the type of your Context:

```
type ColorContextType = null | {
  response: {
    result_info: any, // TODO: type this correctly
    result_list: any[],  // TODO: type this correctly
  }
}

export const ColorContext = createContext<ColorContextType>(null);

export const ProductsProvider = (props) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<ColorContextType>(null);
```

Comment: Thank you. I edited my code, and there's an another error that says 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'response')' even though there's a data in response.

Comment: If you are 100% certain it can never be `null`, use the [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator): `colors!.response`. Otherwise check if it is not null: `if(colors !== null){colors.response etc}`